# Linear Models- What to do about the unknown parameter vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

[image]

I did the first part correctly, but when I computed $B=(X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$, I got the wrong answer. I double checked my calculations on my calculator, all was fine. I think it's because of the unknown parameter vector, but I dont know how to solve this then? Isn't that too many unknowns?

Answer (score 1):

You have data points $(x_i, y_i), 1\le i \le 5$. Your function is of the form:
$$
y = \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2
$$
Considering your data you can rearrange in vectors and matrices to get:
$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}
$$
where $\mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
\vdots \\
y_5
\end{bmatrix}$
, $\boldsymbol{\beta} = \begin{bmatrix}\beta_1 \\ \beta_2\end{bmatrix}$, and 
$
\mathbf{X}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_1^2 \\
\vdots\\
x_5 & x_5^2
\end{bmatrix}
$.
You can get your unknown vector of parameters using 
$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} \Rightarrow \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} \Rightarrow \boldsymbol{\beta} = (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}) ^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y} 
$$
This corresponds to the least-squares solution and the matrix $(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}) ^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T$ is the (left) Moore-Penrose (pseudo) inverse of $\mathbf{X}$.

Doing the calculation I found (rounded to two decimals) $\boldsymbol{\beta} = \begin{bmatrix} 1.76\\
     -0.20 \end{bmatrix}$.
Your function (allowing you to generate the curve) can then be written as:
$$
y = 1.76 x - 0.20 x^2.
$$

Here is a graph showing your data points and the curve drawn using the function above.[image]